# Spring integration kafka 1.2.1.RELEASE : Consumer context error

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am getting error for below consumer configuration details:

NOTE: producer is working fine

Details: Spring integration kafka 1.2.1.RELEASE  (internally uses kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar).
    If I replace it with kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar,the error disappears(by overriding in pom.xml)

```
<int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
        auto-startup="false" channel="inputFromKafka">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
            max-messages-per-poll="5" />
    </int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="consumerProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="auto.offset.reset">smallest</prop>
                <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">10485760</prop> <!-- 10M -->
                <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">5242880</prop>
                <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">1000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
        consumer-timeout="4000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect" consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
        <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
            <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
                group-id="mygroup" max-messages="5000">
                <int-kafka:topic id="test" streams="4" />
            </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
            <!-- <int-kafka:consumer-configuration group-id="default3" value-decoder="kafkaSpecificDecoder" 
                key-decoder="kafkaReflectionDecoder" max-messages="10"> <int-kafka:topic-filter 
                pattern="regextopic.*" streams="4" exclude="false" /> </int-kafka:consumer-configuration> -->
        </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
    </int-kafka:consumer-context>

    <int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
        zk-connect="localhost:2181" zk-connection-timeout="6000"
        zk-session-timeout="400" zk-sync-time="200" />
```

Error:

```
    02:15:28.499 [main] WARN  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter.source': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'consumerContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerContext': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2a1a92' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfiguration] while setting bean property 'consumerConfigurations' with key [mygroup]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a1a92': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#189d083' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConnectionProvider] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at xml.Consumer.main(Consumer.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerContext': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2a1a92' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfiguration] while setting bean property 'consumerConfigurations' with key [mygroup]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a1a92': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#189d083' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConnectionProvider] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:407) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:165) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a1a92': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#189d083' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConnectionProvider] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:41) ~[log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar:1.7.11]
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.logger(Logging.scala:24) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.logger$lzycompute(VerifiableProperties.scala:26) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.logger(VerifiableProperties.scala:26) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:67) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.info(VerifiableProperties.scala:26) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.verify(VerifiableProperties.scala:217) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.scala:95) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean.getObject(ConsumerConfigFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-integration-kafka-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean.getObject(ConsumerConfigFactoryBean.java:30) ~[spring-integration-kafka-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:50) ~[log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar:1.7.11]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
02:15:28.500 [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaInboundChannelAdapter.source': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'consumerContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerContext': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2a1a92' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfiguration] while setting bean property 'consumerConfigurations' with key [mygroup]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a1a92': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#189d083' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConnectionProvider] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
    at xml.Consumer.main(Consumer.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerContext': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2a1a92' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfiguration] while setting bean property 'consumerConfigurations' with key [mygroup]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a1a92': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#189d083' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConnectionProvider] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2a1a92': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#189d083' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConnectionProvider] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#189d083': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d860d7' of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.ConsumerConfigFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d860d7': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your StackTrace shows us this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:50) ~[log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar:1.7.11]
... 59 common frames omitted
```

Looks like you should remove one of them from you `pom.xml`. And I'd say the first one since our Gradle config on the matter looks like:

```
testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.it is helpful.